# Core Graphics Circular Image Blurry

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics

I'm drawing a circle image using core graphics with a modified implementation of this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18664917/1369331)

Here's my source:

```
+ (UIImage*)circularImageWithRadius:(CGFloat)radius color:(UIColor*)color{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, radius*2, radius*2);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rect);
    UIImage* image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

The edges are blurry and I'm not sure why (I thought it didn't matter what resolution the device was, it would work right out of the box).

I tried replacing `CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rect);` with `CGContextFillRect(context, rect);` and that was blurry too. Then I tried `CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, radius*4, radius*4)` and it works perfectly, sharp image and everything (albeit being a a square, not a circle). So I changed back to `CGContextDrawEllipseInRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, radius*4, radius*4)` but this was my result:

[image]

whereas with the rectangle, it was the same size as when using radius*2 but with a much sharper image.

How can I fix my blurry issue and why does `CGContextFillEllipseInRect` not fill the pre-defined image rect?

Answer (score 9):

I feel dumb for having found this immediately after I posted but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965873/drawing-on-the-retina-display-using-coregraphics-image-pixelated) pointed the way.

I just added

```
if(UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions != NULL) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0.0);
} else {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
}
```

instead of just `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);` into my original source and it's crystal clear and sharp.

Comment: I also had this issue. The fix is in setting the scale to 0.0 which draws the image to the scale of the device. The original UIGraphicsBeginImageContext sets opaque to NO and scale to 1.0 by default. I'm pointing this out because I originally thought the fix was related to setting opaque to NO.

Answer (score 0):

**For Swift 3.0**

```
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
        if let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
            /// Do Stuff
        }
```