# The rounded pure color image created by code is blur

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, uislider

In objective-c, I make a circle shape programmatically by following codes:

```
+(UIImage *)makeRoundedImage:(CGSize) size backgroundColor:(UIColor *) backgroundColor cornerRadius:(int) cornerRadius
{
    UIImage* bgImage = [self imageWithColor:backgroundColor andSize:size];;

    CALayer *imageLayer = [CALayer layer];
    imageLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    imageLayer.contents = (id) bgImage.CGImage;

    imageLayer.masksToBounds = YES;
    imageLayer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bgImage.size);
    [imageLayer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *roundedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return roundedImage;
}
```

The imageWithColor method is as following:

```
+(UIImage *)imageWithColor:(UIColor *)color andSize:(CGSize)size
{
    //quick fix, or pop up  CG invalid context 0x0 bug
    if(size.width == 0) size.width = 1;
    if(size.height == 0) size.height = 1;
    //---quick fix

    UIImage *img = nil;

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context,
                                   color.CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
    img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return img;
}
```

Then I used it to create a pure color circle shape image, but what I found is the circle image is not perfect rounded.  As an example, please see following code:

```
CGSize size = CGSizeMake(diameter, diameter);
int r = ceil((float)diameter/2.0);
UIImage *imageNormal = [self makeRoundedImage:size backgroundColor:backgroundColor cornerRadius:r];
[slider setThumbImage:imageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

First I created a circle image, then I set the image as the thumb to a UISlider.  But what shown is as the picture shown below:

[image]

You can see the circle is not an exact circle.  I'm thinking probably it caused by the screen resolution issue?  Because if I use an image resource for the thumb, I need add @2x.  Anybody know the reason?  Thanx in advance.

---

*updated on 8th Aug 2015.*

Further to this question and the answer from @Noah Witherspoon, I found the blurry edge issue has been solved.  But still, the circle looks like being cut.  I used the code as following:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, radius*2.0f, radius*2.0f);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0.0);     
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rect);
UIImage* image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return image;
```

And the circle looks like:

[image]

You can see the edge has been cut.

I changed the code as following:

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, radius*2.0f+4, radius*2.0f+4);
CGRect rectmin = CGRectMake(2.0f, 2.0f, radius*2, radius*2);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, NO, 0.0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rectmin);
UIImage* image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return image;
```

You can see the circle looks better(The top edge and the bottom edge):

[image]

I made the fill rect size smaller, and the edge looks better, but I don't think it's a nice solution.  Still, does anybody know why this happen?

Comment: You don't get a perfect circle because it's being clipped. Draw a smaller circle. Better yet, just use `CGContextFillEllipseInRect` to draw a circle instead of messing with layers.

Comment: Hi @rmaddy, would you please have a look at my updated questions.  The blurry issue has been solved, but still the circle is clipped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your screenshot it looks like you do actually have a circular image, but its scale is wrong—it’s not Retina—so it looks blurry and not-circular. The key thing is that instead of using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` which defaults to a scale of 1.0 (as compared to your screen, which is at a scale of 2.0 or 3.0), you should be using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`. Also, you don’t need to make a layer or a view to draw a circle in an image context.

```
+ (UIImage *)makeCircleImageWithDiameter:(CGFloat)diameter color:(UIColor *)color {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(diameter, diameter), NO, 0 /* scale (0 means “use the current screen’s scale”) */);
    [color setFill];
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, diameter, diameter));
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

Comment: Many thanx @Noah Witherspoon    Your answer is exactly correct.  The issue is caused by using the UIGraphicsBeginImageContext.  I also found the issue by the questions following:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21108504/core-graphics-circular-image-blurry

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a circle every time try this:

```
- (UIImage *)makeCircularImage:(CGSize)size backgroundColor:(UIColor *)backgroundColor {
    CGSize squareSize = CGSizeMake((size.width > size.height) ? size.width : size.height,
                                   (size.width > size.height) ? size.width : size.height);

    UIView *circleView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, squareSize.width, squareSize.height)];
    circleView.layer.cornerRadius = circleView.frame.size.height * 0.5f;
    circleView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    circleView.opaque = NO;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(circleView.bounds.size, circleView.opaque, 0.0);
    [circleView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return img;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Fennelouski, thanx for your answer.  I don't think it's the reason as you said, because I have set the r as diameter/2, but still as you see the picture, it's not a perfect circle.

Comment: Why not simply use `CGContextFillEllipseInRect` to draw a circle. No need for layers.

Comment: @Vigor I used a different approach this time. You could actually use any `UIView` inside this method to produce a circular image.