# CGContextShowTextAtPoint producing non-Retina output on Retina device

Tags: iphone, ios, core-graphics

I'm trying to add a text to an `UIImage` and I'm getting a pixelated drawing.

I have tried some other answers with no success:

- [Drawing on the retina display using CoreGraphics - Image pixelated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6965873/drawing-on-the-retina-display-using-coregraphics-image-pixelated?lq=1)
- [Retina display core graphics font quality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5414631/retina-display-core-graphics-font-quality)
- [Drawing with Core Graphics looks chunky on Retina display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291510/drawing-with-core-graphics-looks-chunky-on-retina-display)

My code:

```
-(UIImage *)addText:(UIImage *)imgV text:(NSString *)text1
{
   int w = self.frame.size.width * 2;
   int h = self.frame.size.height * 2;
   CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
   CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate
         (NULL, w, h, 8, 4 * w, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

   CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h), imgV.CGImage);    
   CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1);

   char* text = (char *)[text1 cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
   CGContextSelectFont(context, "Arial", 24, kCGEncodingMacRoman);

   // Adjust text;

   CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextInvisible);
   CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 0, 0, text, strlen(text));

   CGPoint pt = CGContextGetTextPosition(context);
   float posx = (w/2 - pt.x)/2.0;
   float posy = 54.0;    
   CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill);
   CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 255, 255, 255, 1.0);

   CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, posx, posy, text, strlen(text));

   CGImageRef imageMasked = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
   CGContextRelease(context);
   CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

   return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageMasked];
}
```

[image: example of jagged image]

Comment: Have you considered using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` and the related functions instead?

Comment: Yes but the edges of the text keep jagged.

Comment: Which value did you pass for the scale factor? Also, please edit your question to include a screenshot of the “pixelated”, “jagged” text.

Comment: image added to the question

Comment: So, which value did you pass for the scale factor to `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` that got you the same result?

Comment: I tried passing 2.0 and 1.0 and `[UIScreen mainScreen].scale`

Comment: The correct value is `0.0`, which will automatically detect the correct scale factor for the main screen. But if you've tried `2.0` and that didn't help, then your problem must be something else that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like Peter said, use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions`. You might want to pass image.scale to the scale attribute (where image.scale is the scale of one of the images you're drawing), or simply use [UIScreen mainScreen].scale.

This code can be made simpler overall. Try something like:

```
// Create the image context
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_baseImage.size, NO, _baseImage.scale);

// Draw the image
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, _baseImage.size.width, _baseImage.size.height);
[_baseImage drawInRect:rect];

// Get a vertically centered rect for the text drawing
rect.origin.y = (rect.size.height - FONT_SIZE) / 2 - 2;
rect = CGRectIntegral(rect);
rect.size.height = FONT_SIZE;

// Draw the text
UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE];
[[UIColor whiteColor] set];
[text drawInRect:rect withFont:font lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByClipping alignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];

// Get and return the new image
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return image;
```

Where `text` is an NSString object.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the exact same problem and posted a question last night to which no-one replied. I have combined fnf's suggested changes with Clif Viegas's answer in the following question:
 [CGContextDrawImage draws image upside down when passed UIImage.CGImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506622/cgcontextdrawimage-draws-image-upside-down-when-passed-uiimage-cgimage)

to come up with the solution. My addText method is slightly different from yours:

+(UIImage *)addTextToImage:(UIImage *)img text:(NSString *)text1{

```
int w = img.size.width;
int h = img.size.height;

CGSize size = CGSizeMake(w, h);
if (UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions != NULL) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0);
} else {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
}
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();


CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0,h);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h), img.CGImage);

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1);

char* text = (char *)[text1 cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];// \"05/05/09\";

CGContextSelectFont(context, "Times New Roman", 14, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode(context, kCGTextFill);

CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0, 0, 0, 1);

//rotate text

CGContextSetTextMatrix(context, CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( -M_PI/8 ));

CGContextShowTextAtPoint(context, 70, 88, text, strlen(text));

CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
```

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImg;

}

In summary, what I have done is add

```
if (UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions != NULL) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0.0);
} else {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
}
```

Remove

// CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, w, h, 8, 4 * w, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

and put

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```

instead. But this causes the image to be upside down. Hence I put

```
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0,h);
CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
```

just before 
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, w, h), img.CGImage);

This way you can use CG functions instead of using drawInRect etc.

Don't forget

UIGraphicsEndImageContext

at the end. Hope this helps.